# Can't get an HTML Sprite to work correctly

Tags: html, css, sprite

I am trying to add a sprite to a web page but the sprite is not appearing correctly. I want it to appear fixed to the right of the header. It is failing miserably! What am I doing wrong?

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Here is what I have in my style secti]

Here is what I have in my style section:

```
//...a bunch of other stuff
#HomeMenu{
        position: relative;
        }
        .linkedin {
        display: inline-block;
        left: 0px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 18px;
        background: url('Social-Media-Icons.jpg')-10px 0;

    }

    .facebook {
        left: 63px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
        height: 18px;
        background: url('Social-Media-Icons.jpg')0 0;

    }
```

Here is what I have for my header section:

```
<nav id="HomeMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Interest and Goals</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a></li>
                <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/"></a></li>
            </ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here is what finally worked for me:

```
<style>
    .linkedin {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 16px;
        height: 18px;
        background-image: url('Social-Media-Icons.jpg');
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    .facebook {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 16px;
        height: 18px;
        background-image: url('Social-Media-Icons.jpg');
        background-position: -48px 0;
    }
</style> 

    <nav id="HomeMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interest and Goals</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a></li>
        <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using *IDs* in your CSS (`#facebook`, `#linkedin`), but *classes*  in your HTML - won't work that way...

Change your CSS selectors to `.facebook` and `.linkedin` (or the other way round: change the HTML attributes in your `a` tags to `id="facebook` and `id="linkedin`)

Apart from that, your `a` tags don't have any content. Since `a` tags are inline elements, this results in a size with 0 width, i.e. invisible. Change them to `display: inline-block` to fix this:

```css
#HomeMenu {
  position: relative;
}

.linkedin {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 95px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x60/fa0');
}

.facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 95px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x60/3be');
}
```

```html
<nav id="HomeMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Interest and Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. I updated the code with your fixes. Sorry I had a similar version before but I forgot to change the classes back. This is essentially where I was before. Anytime I add any parameters to the background-image for .facebook the images disappear. Why is that happening?

Comment: thanks for the quick responses. I greatly appreciate them. I have attached an image of what I am currently seeing.

Comment: so you have to adjust the `width` and `height` of the containers, and add `background-position` - usually two values, horizontal and vertical, can also be negative values to move the visible part of the image to the left.